# Fetching top data from the table for each primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a series of foreign key with each key constitutes to more than one row in the table. How can I fetch only the top row which matches the specified condition?

I have table like this

```
ID    NAME      DATE
----------------------
1     abc       5/10/15
1     abc       6/11/15
2     pqr       7/11/15
2     pqr       8/10/15
3     xyz       9/12/15
```

I need to output to be like this

where the condition is date > 5/11/15 and ID in (1,2)

```
ID   NAME   DATE
-----------------
1    abc    6/11/15
2    pqr    7/11/15
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using and define what you mean by "top".

Comment: Also by default if am not ordering by the date, it is ordered in ascending order.
Can I get the data in the order in which I have specified in the condition like (2,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want using `row_number()`.  I'm not sure exactly what you want though.  My best guess is getting the row with the smallest date that meets the conditions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
      where date > '2015-11-05' and id in (1, 2)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be DESC?

Comment: Thanks using row number and partition worked. Got the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row as long as no other row has same name and an earlier date:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where not exists (select * from tablename t2
                  where t2.name = t1.name
                    and t2.date < t1.date
                    and t2.date > '5/11/15' and t2.ID in (1,2))
  and t1.date > '5/11/15' and t1.ID in (1,2)
```

`JOIN` alternative, perhaps better MySQL answer:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
    join (select name, min(date) from tablename
          where date > '5/11/15' and t2.ID in (1,2)
          group by name) as t2
      on t1.name = t2.name and t1.date = t2.date
where t1.date > '5/11/15' and t1.ID in (1,2)
```

Core SQL-99.

Comment: That won't do what he asked for, xyz from his example will be selected

Comment: Didn't notice that part. Will soon edit. Stay tuned!

Comment: No idea.. I'm more of an oracle guy:P